# Specflow - How to refer browser objects across scenarios under the same feature

Tags: selenium, web, selenium-chromedriver, specflow, gherkin

I am new to specflow and I am using specflow to test a website.

I have just one feature with 2 scenarios.

In the first scenario, i just invoke the browser and navigate to the home page of the application under test. I am using selenium chrome driver for this.

In the second scenario, I need to refer the instance of the chrome driver to access the objects in the web page.

However, it seems like the page is not identified. I am getting the message '..object reference not set..

I am creating the instance of the driver under under the main class as public static

Please advise on how I could refer the instance of the driver across methods which belongs to all the scenarios under the same feature

Thanks
SK

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research, I identified that the issue was related to the sequence of execution of scenarios under the feature.

I had 3 scenarios which should be executed in a sequential order. ( There might be people who argue that this is not the ideal case though). The issue was, the scenario which I was expecting to be executed as third in the sequence was getting executed as the first scenario.

By renaming the scenarios alphabetically, I was able to control the execution flow. (I believe that is the way to control execution flow in nunit) and this resolved my bug.

Thanks
SK